# Derivative of $-e^y = 0$?

Tags: analysis, exponential-function

I stumbled upon this on wolfram alpha and still wonder why $-e^x$ equals $0$ (third step).

[image]

Comment: You're differentiating with respect to $y$, so $-e^x$ is treated as a constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is assuming that $x$ and $y$ are independent variables and as you're differentiating with respect to $y$, that term vanishes since it doesn't contain any $y$'s

Answer (score 0):

Variable $x$ is treated like a constant (becouse you are differentiating with respect to $y$). So $$(-e^x)'=(-e^C)'=(C)'=0.$$